# How to change theme in ICEfaces 3

Tags: maven, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

I am using Maven to download `ICEfaces` dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>icefaces</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>icefaces-compat</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>icefaces-facelets</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I checked the Binaries and the Sources from the official ICEfaces website, both zip files does not contain the `xmlhttp` folder which contains the CSS files for the themes.

Adding the following in `web.xml` file doesn't change anything:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.icefaces.ace.theme</param-name>
    <param-value>rime</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: I have never used icefaces, but going through the documentation it looks like themes are only supported for ACE components, and not ICE (compat) components that you have in your dependencies. Any reason why you don't use ACE, since ICE seems to be legacy?

Comment: @PredragMaric A big part of the application was built using ICEfaces 1.7, I'm upgrading to version 3, I wanna avoid changing extremely the markup and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the styling resources for each page in your application with regular `<link>` tags or the JSF `<h:outputStylesheet>` component .

The styling resources (images and theme.css file) for the rime and sam themes could be found in [icefaces/icefaces-ace-3.0.0.jar.zip](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/icefaces/icefaces-ace-3.0.0.jar.zip).

The directory of the rime theme is:

```
META-INF/resources/icefaces.ace/themes/rime/
```